# Error in creating a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to retrieve values by joining two tables (the customer and enquiry table),then i'm trying to store the retrieved values into another table that would come in handy for reasons irrelevant here.And then i'm finally deleting the retrieved values from the enquiry table. When i'm trying to execute the stored procedure i'm getting the following error shown in the screenshot below.
[image: MySQL Error]

how do i resolve this error?

Stored Procedure:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `backup_eq`(
    IN `eq` VARCHAR(15), IN `mail` VARCHAR(30), IN `dates` DATE, IN `cmp` VARCHAR(10), IN `rea` VARCHAR(50)) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
SELECT eqno into @eno,Date1 into @d,cmpname into @c,subject into @s,cid into @cd 
FROM `enquiry` NATURAL JOIN `customer` 
WHERE eqno=eq and email=mail and cmpname=cmp and Date=dates; 
INSERT INTO `enquiryBin`(`Eqno`, `Date1`, `Cmpname`, `Subject`, `CID`, `Reason`) 
VALUES (@eno,@d,@c,@s,@cd,rea); 
DELETE FROM `enquiry` 
WHERE eqno=eq and cid=@cd and cmpname=cmp and Date1=dates; 
END
```

The create table statements of the two tables are given below

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `CID` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `phone` bigint(20) NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE `customer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CID`);

  CREATE TABLE `enquiry` (
  `Eqno` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Date1` date NOT NULL,
  `Cmpname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CID` int(15) NOT NULL
)

  ALTER TABLE `enquiry`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Eqno`,`Cmpname`,`CID`,`Date1`)
```

Comment: Is the column named `Date1` or `Date`? You have `and Date = dates` in the `WHERE` clause, but I don't see that column in your tables.

Comment: @Barmar, dates is one of the procedure's IN parameters.

Comment: I'm not asking about `dates`, I'm asking about `Date` versus `Date1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT eqno into @eno,Date1 into @d,cmpname into @c,subject into @s,cid into @cd
```

Should be

```
SELECT eqno, Date1, cmpname, subject, cid INTO @eno, @d, @c, @s, @cd
```

That is, name all columns in the select-list separately from the `INTO` clause.

Refer to syntax documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: Another option is to use variable assignment: `SELECT @eno := eqno, @d := Date1, ...`

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for all those variables, just use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query, and a `JOIN` in the `DELETE` query.

```
INSERT INTO enquiryBin (`Eqno`, `Date1`, `Cmpname`, `Subject`, `CID`, `Reason`)
SELECT eqno, Date1, cmpname, subject, cid, rea
FROM FROM `enquiry` NATURAL JOIN `customer` 
WHERE eqno=eq and email=mail and cmpname=cmp and Date1 = dates; 

DELETE e FROM enquiry AS e
NATURAL JOIN customer 
WHERE eqno = eq AND email = mail AND cmpname = cmp AND Date1 = dates
```